# Test if a method is called by an object

Tags: rspec

I am fairly new to Rspec and Rails. I want to test that the execute method won't be called if the run method is not run with confirm as true. How should I write this rspec test?

```
class Release

  def run(confirm=false)
    execute if confirm
  end

  def execute
    # do something
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it "should not execute without confirmation" do
  release = Release.new
  release.run
  expect(release).not_to have_received(:execute)
end
```